# How to add a second custom header element to WooCommerce Storefront Powerpack

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am using the following code for adding an extra custom text element to the Powerpack Header Customization:

```
// Adds the text element to the powerpack header components
function sp_header_components_custom_text( $components ) {
    $components['text'] = array(
    'title' => __( 'Custom Text', 'storefront-powerpack' ),
    'hook'  => 'sp_header_custom_text_output'
    );

    return $components;
}
add_filter( 'sp_header_components', 'sp_header_components_custom_text' );

// Adds text area output to the Storefront header
function sp_header_custom_text_output() {
    echo '<div class="custom-text">';

        echo 'Some custom text added to header in Storefront Powerpack';

    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'sp_header_custom_text_output' );
```

But I am wondering how to add a second custom text element? Copying the code and adding a “_two” to the function names doesn’t work unfortunately.

Looking forward for some help and advice!

Kind regards Abidin

Comment: Please add a code example here from GitHub

Comment: Added the code from the "github" link to the question. Removed the "github" link since it doesn't link to any project, just to a single file (and the entire content of that file is in this question)...